# Bicep module outputs wrong resource id

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have subscription scoped bicep deployment, including some modules to create content for resource group. In one module I create VNET and I try to get back its resource ID `output vnetId string = vnet.id`, on another module I'd like to use this value and I have set properly the dependsOn. But there is problem, seems the output ID doesn't contain resource groups part `/subscriptions/<subs>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-weu/subnets/portal`

Does it have something with using subscription level deployment? (`az deployment sub create ...`)

**UPDATE**: I just found this [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#remarks-1), which does explain the missing resource group part, but does not explain why `vnet.id` in module with `targetScope = 'resourceGroup'` returns subscription resource id instead of "full" resource id.

**UPDATE - CODE**

*network.bicep*

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'

param vnetName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2020-11-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  ... 
}

output vnetId string = vnet.id
```

main.bicep

```
targetScope = 'subscription'


module networkRgResources 'network.bicep' = {
  name: 'networkRgResources'
  scope: resourceGroup(networkRg.name)
  params: {
    location: location
    vnetName: vnetName
  }
}

module sharedRgResources 'shared.bicep' = {
  name: 'sharedRgResources'
  scope: resourceGroup(sharedRg.name)
  params: {
    vnetId: networkRgResources.outputs.vnetId
  }
  dependsOn: [
    networkRgResources
  ]
}
```

inside shared module the vnetId is without resource groups

**UPDATE 2**
I cannot simulate this, but seems I have some strange race conditions in my code, now it seems it is working fine.

Comment: Can you share the code that contains the output?  There is a known issue (the remark you found) with using the resourceId() function at subscription scope but I wouldn't expect bicep to be affected by that...

Comment: now I am using `output vnetId string = resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', vnetName)` before it was just `output vnetId string = vnet.id`

Comment: Can you create an issue in github.com/azure/bicep and paste your code and write which version of bicep you use? This is quite disturbing case as I do use same technique and it was working for me.

Comment: @Zveratko - can you also explain the "dependsOn" part? if you use resource or module symbols, you do not need to add dependsOn properties - they are added automatically by bicep compiler

Comment: @Miq I mean the module that is using the vnetId output has properly set dependOn Vnet module so it is created first, do you think it is unnecessary?

Comment: @Zveratko - can you show your code? if you use in the second module in params section something like this: `vnetModule.outputs.vnetId` then additional dependsOn is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   Using the ‘resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', vnetName)’ can be a solution. If you want to try a different approach, then you can use something like below: -

Vnetdeploy.bicep

```
 targetScope = 'subscription'
 resource rg 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-01-01' existing = {
 name: 'xxxxx-xxxxxx'
  }
 module vnet './vnet.bicep' = {
  name: 'vnetdeployment'
 scope: rg
params: {
   vnetname: 'vnet2'
 }
  }

output vnetID string = vnet.outputs.virtualNetworkID
```

vnet.bicep. i.e., VNET Module

```
param vnetname string
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2020-08-01' = {
 name: vnetname
 location: 'EastUS'
 properties: {
  addressSpace: {
  addressPrefixes: [
    '10.0.2.0/24'
  ]
}
subnets: [
  {
    name: 'subnet1'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/27'
    }
  }
]
}
  }
 output virtualNetworkID string = virtualNetwork.id
```

Output: -

[image: Bicep template output]